# How can I open my Nav Bar with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navbar, addeventlistener, nav, queryselector

I want to see the my nav-list when I click the 3-line tab.
but nothing happened when I click it.
plz let me know how to do it. TT
here is the codes what I write.

I want to see the my nav-list when I click the 3-line tab.
but nothing happened when I click it.
plz let me know how to do it. TT
here is the codes what I write.

as the page shrinks, the 3-line tab appears.
and I use google chrome.

```js
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav{
    height: 10vh;
    background: black;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.landing{
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} 

.landing h1{
    margin: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: purple;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

    .line {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background: white;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    nav{
        position: relative;
    }

    .burger{
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        right: 5%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
    }

    .nav-links{
        position: fixed;
        background: black;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -20%);
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -20%);
        transition: all 1s ease-out;
    }

    .nav-links.open{
        clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -20%);
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -20%);
    }
    .landing{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>FRIENDS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CHARACTER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUDY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VISITORS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="landing">
        <img src="circle.png" alt="dots">
        <h1>FRIENDS<h1>
    </section>


    
    
    <script type="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why this sudden influx of people who post screenshots of their code instead of pasting it?! Isn’t creating a screenshot, uploading it, then embedding it a lot more work than pasting code?

Comment: Please add code snippet on your post